# Cómo extraer datos según un criterio en Excel?

Tags: excel

Cordial Saludos,

Tengo un libro de excel con dos hojas, en la primera hoja tengo todos los datos y en la segunda hoja quiero extraer las actividades diferentes realizadas por la misma persona en la misma fecha, es decir tener en cuenta el id, nombre, actividad y fecha. Ejemplo: si el empleado Carlos Perez tiene doble actividad el día 23 de mayo me traiga los datos del empleado y las dos actividades de lo contrario no me traiga los datos de ese empleado.
Estoy utilizando esta fórmula aunque no trae los datos esperados, espero me podáis ayudar, os agradezco de antemano.

```
=INDICE(Sheet1!$A$2:$L$3424;COINCIDIR(0;CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$2:$A5;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3424;$B$2:$B5;Sheet1!$B$2:$B$3424;$C$2:$C5;Sheet1!$C$2:$C$3424;$D$2:$D5;Sheet1!$D$2:$D$3424)+(CONTAR.SI($M$2;Sheet1!$K$2:$K$3424)=0);0);COLUMNA(I4))
```

Estructura de Datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado obtenido y Resultado Esperado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin un ejemplo de la estructura de datos en Sheet1, que es de donde los estás extrayendo, no se puede ayudar en condiciones. Además, no queda clara tu pregunta. ¿Qué parámetros usas para la búsqueda? ¿Sólo nombre?¿Nombre e Id?¿Nombre yf echa? ¿Referencia? ¿Más parámetros? Lo mejor es siempre intentar usar algún dato que no tenga duplicados.

Comment: @Esei Gracias por la sugerencia, la idea es que se extraiga todos los datos del empleado siempre y cuando cumpla con la condición de que tenga doble actividad el mismo día.

Comment: Mirando tus datos de origen, entonces habría que coger, por ejemplo, las filas 21 y 22 porque son de la misma persona en el mismo día. ¿Correcto?

Comment: @Esei, No, porque el dato que quiero que verifique es que la actividad sea diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una tabla dinámica, filtro avanzado y también esta la función FILTRAR

Esta formula funciona en ese caso.

```
=FILTRAR(Hoja1!B2:J31,(Hoja1!B2:B31="name1")*(Hoja1!D2:D31="Activity1")*(Hoja1!I2:I31=FECHANUMERO("2022-5-20")),"")
```

**Usar Tabla**

Si conviertes el rango de datos en una tabla excel, la escritura y lectura de la formula es mejor.

Para convertir un rango de datos en tabla, selecciona el rango de datos incluyendo encabezados -> presiona Control + t -> Aceptar -> En la ficha "Diseño de Tabla" pon un nombre a tu tabla, es bueno iniciarlo con tbl, ejemplo: tblDatos, de ese modo podrás hacer referencia a ese nombre en las formulas.

la formula queda así si pones tblDatos como nombre de tabla.

Observa como se hace referencia al rango de datos con tblDatos, para hacer referencia a las columnas se usa el nombre de la tabla y entre corchetes el nombre de la columna, según el encabezado que tiene la tabla.

```
=FILTRAR(tblDatos,(tblDatos[Names]="name1")*(tblDatos[Activity]="Activity1")*(tblDatos[Date]=FECHANUMERO("2022-5-20")),"")
```

En esta formula se pone el criterio de filtro de manera directa, pero se puede hacer con referencias a celdas, de ese modo tecleas el criterio en las celdas que corresponda y se aplica el filtro, así no tienes que estar modificando la formula cuando quieres cambiar los criterios de filtrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]